# c# RavenDB embedded optimize

Tags: c#, .net, database, optimization, ravendb

I have a database (RavenDB) which needs to be able to handle 300 queries (Full text search) every 10 seconds. To increase peformance I splitted up the database so I have multiple documentStores
my Code:

```
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int taskcnt = 0;
        int sum = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 7, new Action<int>((x) =>
            {
                for(int docomentStore = 0;docomentStore < 5; docomentStore++)
                {
                    var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    Task<IList<eBayItem>> task = new Task<IList<eBayItem>>(Database.ExecuteQuery, new Filter()
                    {
                        Store = "test" + docomentStore,
                        MaxPrice = 600,
                        MinPrice = 200,
                        BIN = true,
                        Keywords = new List<string>() { "Canon", "MP", "Black" },
                        ExcludedKeywords = new List<string>() { "G1", "T3" }
                    });
                    task.ContinueWith((list) => {
                        stopWatch.Stop();
                        sum += stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
                        taskcnt++;
                        if (taskcnt == 300)
                        {
                            watch.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine("Average time: " + (sum / (float)300).ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + watch.Elapsed.ToString() + "ms");

                        }

                    });
                    task.Start();
                }

            }));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
```

- Average query time: 514,13 ms
- Total time: 00:01:29.9108016

The code where I query ravenDB:

```
        public static IList<eBayItem> ExecuteQuery(object Filter)
    {
        IList<eBayItem> items;
        Filter filter = (Filter)Filter;

        if (int.Parse(filter.Store.ToCharArray().Last().ToString()) > 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filter.Store); return null;
        }
        using (var session = Shards[filter.Store].OpenSession())
        {
            var query = session.Query<eBayItem, eBayItemIndexer>().Where(y => y.Price <= filter.MaxPrice && y.Price >= filter.MinPrice);

            query = filter.Keywords.ToArray()
            .Aggregate(query, (q, term) =>
                q.Search(xx => xx.Title, term, options: SearchOptions.And));
            if (filter.ExcludedKeywords.Count > 0)
            {
                query = filter.ExcludedKeywords.ToArray().Aggregate(query, (q, exterm) =>
                q.Search(it => it.Title, exterm, options: SearchOptions.Not));
            }
            items = query.ToList<eBayItem>();
        }
        return items;
    }
```

And the initialization of RavenDB:

```
        static Dictionary<string, EmbeddableDocumentStore> Shards = new Dictionary<string, EmbeddableDocumentStore>();
    public static void Connect()
    {
        Shards.Add("test0", new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test.db" });
        Shards.Add("test1", new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test1.db" });
        Shards.Add("test2", new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test2.db" });
        Shards.Add("test3", new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test3.db" });
        Shards.Add("test4", new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test4.db" });
        foreach (string  key in Shards.Keys)
        {
            EmbeddableDocumentStore store = Shards[key];
            store.Initialize();
            IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(eBayItemIndexer).Assembly, store);
        }
    }
```

How can I optimize my code so my total time is lower ? Is it good to divide my database up in 5 different ones ?

**EDIT:** The program has only 1 documentStore instead of 5. (As sugested by [Ayende Rahien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753256/c-sharp-ravendb-embedded-optimize/15755871#15755871))
Also this is the Query on its own:

```
Price_Range:[* TO Dx600] AND Price_Range:[Dx200 TO NULL] AND Title:(Canon) AND Title:(MP) AND Title:(Black) -Title:(G1) -Title:(T3)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't good.
Use a single embedded RavenDB. If you need sharding, this involved multiple machines.

In general, RavenDB queries are in the few ms each. You need to show what your queries looks like (you can call ToString() on them to see that).

Having shards of RavenDB in this manner means that all of them are fighting for CPU and IO

Comment: Price_Range:[* TO Dx600] AND Price_Range:[Dx200 TO NULL] AND Title:(Canon) AND Title:(MP) AND Title:(Black) -Title:(G1) -Title:(T3)
This is my query.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this was the top search result I got.

I had the same problem that my queries were taking 500ms. It now takes 100ms by applying the following search practices: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/querying/static-indexes/searching